# How to make an expandable list within an expandable list in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Just learning HTML and CSS and wondering how I could have an expandable list within an expandable list. I have the problem that the second expandable list is already expanded when I click the first expandable list. Yo dawg, I heard you like expandable lists....

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<style>

body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: Arial;
}

#nav {
background-color: black;
}

#navbar {
margin: auto;
width: 960px;
text-align:left;

}

#nav ul{
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
padding:0;
margin: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px;
display: block;
}

    #nav ul li:hover {
background-color: silver;
}

#nav ul ul{
display: none;
margin: 0;
background-color: black;
position: absolute;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

#nav ul ul li {
display:block;
}

#nav ul ul ul{
display: none;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 110px;
margin-top: -52px;
background-color: black;

}

#nav ul ul li:hover ul{
display: block;
}

#nav ul ul ul li {
display: block;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">YouTube</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Top Videos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [child (direct descendant)](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) selector `>` instead of the descendant selector

```
#nav ul>li:hover>ul {
display: block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bbcy/1/)

What you are currently doing is saying: when hovering over the `li` set any decendant `ul`, no matter what the depth, to `display:block`.

The new code says: when hovering over the `li` set any `ul`s that are children (or direct descendants) of that `li` to `display:block`. Any `ul`s nested deeper will be untouched.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really useful. Didn't know about the child selector. Still learning I guess...